# Pop-up window that can be controlled remotely?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I was requested to put a pop-up window on each 3rd usage of an app but I have to control this pop-up so I can take it off whenever I want or change it remotely.

I don't want an alert view, just a background that I will insert myself, that can be controlled from a server.

What's the easy way to do that? Do I need my own server that the app connects to and get a "boolean number" whether to remove it or play it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I handled this was with a configuration file on an amazon s3 bucket. The application downloads the configuration file, and checks the appropriate values for how to behave. It's worked fairly well so far.

http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-use-Amazon-s3-for-web-hosting.html

As for the window, you should just use a modal.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1771684&seqNum=5

Comment: no other way ? is it takes time to download it from amazon? i need to pop up at start-up ..

Comment: I'm not certain what your needs are, but I download my configuration file on every startup of the application, and store it locally, so its values are always available. It should only take a second to download if the device has access to the internet. However, I can't promise you won't run into a race condition in downloading the file.